# Adding two bib files in moderncv class

Tags: bibliographies, moderncv

Suppose, I am having two publication list one related to masters and other related to doctorate and I am using `moderncv` class for building my cv. My question is that should I use a single bib file or have I to use two bib files? But, I want to display the publication list as masters and doctorate separately. How to do that?

I tried with a single bib file (pubmaster) and the MWE is as follows. should I include one more bib file for displaying the publications list related to doctorate?

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\recomputelengths                             % required when changes 
\firstname{First}
\familyname{Second}                   % optional, 
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Career Objective}

\section{Skill Sets}
\cventry{Languages:} {C, C++, R, HTML Core Java and AspectJ}{}{} {}{}
\cventry{Operating Systems:} {Windows and Linux}{}{} {}{}
\cventry{Packages} {Microsoft Office}{}{} {}{}
\cventry{Scripts:} {Java Script and VB Script}{}{} {}{}
\cventry{Applications}{\LaTeX, Spreadsheet, IBM RSA, Matlab}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{Visualization Tools}{Edraw Max, ORA and Pajek}{}{}{}{}

\section{Achievements, Awards and Honors}
\cventry{2016}{International Biographical Centre (IBC)}{Listed in ``Top 100 Professionals, 2016''}{Cambridge, Engaland}{}{}


\section{Professional Affiliations}



\section{Professional Activities}

\cventry{2016}{Invited Reviewer}{International Journal of Computers and Applications}{Taylor \& Francis}{}{}



\section{Areas of Interest}
\cvlistitem {Databases, Software Engineering, Aspect-oriented Programming, Program Slicing and Service-oriented Architecture}


\section{Workshops/Short Term Courses Attended}

\section{Extra Co-Curricular Activities}
\cvlistitem{Took a lead in different college level \& inter college level Football Tournaments.}

\section{Courses \& Teaching}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{pubmaster} 
\section{Personal Details}
\vspace{1.0cm}
\begin{flushright}
\par
\par
\par
\par
\textbf{AABC}
\end{flushright}


\textbf{India}\\
\textbf{Last Updated: \today}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That question has been asked before. It doesn't matter if you want to separate between private publications and university publications, articles nd books and online media, or masters pubs and doctoral pubs; the mechanism of using keywords or filters is the same.

Comment: Looking at your document you are not using `biblatex`, the package that can easily do what you want. You are using the old system. Because the old system cannot do what you want easily, a small group of very clever people introduced `biblatex`.

Comment: Since you are not using `biblatex`, I have removed the `biblatex` tag and added the more generic 'bibliographies' tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `biblatex` you can use package `multibib`.

You need then to run first the MWE, then run `bibtex master.aux` to create the publication list and then run `bibtex doc.aux` to create the second bibliography ...

In the following MWE I marked the important codes with `% <===========`:

```
% needs: bibtex doc.aux % <==============================================
% needs: bibtex master.aux % <===========================================
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{pubmaster.bib}
@article{latex,
  title={{\LaTeX} for the study},
  author={Firstname Surname},
  year={2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{pubdoc.bib}
@article{latexd,
  title={{\LaTeX} to write a doctor thesis},
  author={Firstname Surname},
  year={2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[9pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\recomputelengths                             % required when changes 

% <=====================================================================
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{master,doc}{{Published as master},{Published as doc}}
% <=====================================================================

\firstname{First}
\familyname{Second}                   % optional, 


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Career Objective}

\section{Skill Sets}
\cventry{Languages:} {C, C++, R, HTML Core Java and AspectJ}{}{} {}{}
\cventry{Operating Systems:} {Windows and Linux}{}{} {}{}
\cventry{Packages} {Microsoft Office}{}{} {}{}
\cventry{Scripts:} {Java Script and VB Script}{}{} {}{}
\cventry{Applications}{\LaTeX, Spreadsheet, IBM RSA, Matlab}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{Visualization Tools}{Edraw Max, ORA and Pajek}{}{}{}{}

\section{Achievements, Awards and Honors}
\cventry{2016}{International Biographical Centre (IBC)}{Listed in ``Top 100 Professionals, 2016''}{Cambridge, Engaland}{}{}


\section{Professional Affiliations}



\section{Professional Activities}

\cventry{2016}{Invited Reviewer}{International Journal of Computers and Applications}{Taylor \& Francis}{}{}



\section{Areas of Interest}
\cvlistitem {Databases, Software Engineering, Aspect-oriented Programming, Program Slicing and Service-oriented Architecture}


\section{Workshops/Short Term Courses Attended}

\section{Extra Co-Curricular Activities}
\cvlistitem{Took a lead in different college level \& inter college level Football Tournaments.}

\section{Courses \& Teaching}

\nocitemaster{*} % <====================================================
\bibliographystylemaster{plain}
\bibliographymaster{pubmaster}
\nocitedoc{*}
\bibliographystyledoc{plain}
\bibliographydoc{pubdoc} % <============================================

\section{Personal Details}
\vspace{1.0cm}
\begin{flushright}
\par
\par
\par
\par
\textbf{AABC}
\end{flushright}


\textbf{India}\\
\textbf{Last Updated: \today}
\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image]